# How can I count part of a string in a particular row in python?

Tags: python, count, substring

[Data example showing 'category' row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtXY8.jpg)

I have the following data in a 'category' row, from a CSV file I've read in python using DictReader.

I can use the below counter to count instances of each category, but what I want to do is count how many times 'F' appears. ie. count part of the string, not the whole string.

Your help is greatly appreciated :)

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter()
for row in data:
   counts[row['category']] += 1

print("Age/Gender Categories:")
for k, v in sorted(counts.items()):
   print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))
```

this shows:

Age/Gender Categories:
ES H: 11
JU H: 3
SE F: 38
SE H: 512
V1 F: 51
V1 H: 482
V2 F: 18
V2 H: 222
V3 F: 5
V3 H: 31
V4 H: 3

but I want it to show:

F: 112

I've also tried the following code which I think is getting close?

```
counts = Counter()
for row in data:
    counts[row['category']] += 1
    
gender = category.items()

for k in gender:
        print(k)
```

Comment: Can you include a part of what `data` so we can test it? Also are you literally just looking for how many `F` appear in your data? Or are you looking for how often _each_ individual letter appears in your `data`?

Comment: Thank you @HenryEcker, yes I'm literally just looking for how many `F` appear in my data. I'm not sure how to include part of the data sorry but each different category is as above, eg. "ES H". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are trying to count the Fs in 4th letter of each data.

```
count=0
for i in arr:
    if i[3] == "F":
        count+=1

print("F:{}".format(count))
```

Comment: thank you so much!! that worked perfectly :D I know it's so simple but I'm new to python so that was such a help!